# Sharepoint 2013 make progress report auto monthly

Tags: 2013, list

I have 2 lists. No. 1 is for data entry, this list has column name, field1(number), field2(number) and a calculated column (sum = field 1 + field2).

How to make the second list as a progress report (monthly). For example in the second  list, the first column is the 1st day of every month and it should be the triggered value to update the list from the first list. 2nd is the lookup column from the first. and 3rd column is the lookup calculated column from the first list.

Can it be done automatically, the 2nd list is updated on every 1st day of the month. Hope somebody can assist me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/services/shared_sharepointonline/sharepoint/) that might be easier with an action called [recurrence](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/run-tasks-on-a-schedule/).  Have a look at this article also where data is moved based on the recurrence task.

http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/

Comment: Appreciate that but do you have OOTB solution.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by OOTB? In order to trigger an event to update your list you will need some sort of work flow.

Comment: Good. My requirement is to make something like a staff performance progress. The first list is where supervisor enter marks together with calculated columns total and percentages. The second list is the monitoring on monthly basis for individual and for group performance. The second list is a report to the boss. How do i write a formula for date column so that it is on auto and able to keep old value for the past month and the value is added to the current month. The future months is zero. Based on the formula I am able to plot a S curve graph.